# Java Method(Overloading)

Tags: java, function-overloading

Ребята перегрузка методов выполняетсь во время компиляции(Compile-Time)  или во время выполнения (Run-Time) ?

Answer (score 1):

Overloading - compile time полиморфизм. Overriding - run time

Comment: В C++ и C#  это так как ты сказал , но в Java это так ли ?